# How to view Parse Server logs in Parse Dashboard?

Tags: logging, log-files, parse-server

I'm using **parse-server 2.2.14**, with **parse-dashboard 1.0.14**.
According to [this merged pull request](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/1502), logs can be viewed from the dashboard.
But my dashboard just show "`No logs in the last 30 days`" whereas there actually are logs on the server.

How to make server logs appear in the dashboard?

Thanks